# How to change data on a specific calendar day

Tags: android, date, events, triggers

I have an app on Android with a DataBase. This database has tables with ChangeDate columns, where I keep dates when some actions need to happen. For example, 2014-03-17..2014-05-18 and etc. The problem for me is that if I'm comparing for about 200 db records with today date on the app start , it will make my app heavier.
Is there another way or maybe a type of trigger for such things? Maybe you can advise something. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking against 200 dates will take an instant so do not worry about the load for such a small number.

For other solutions, it depends on what those actions are. If this is just some actions to take when the app start, then the solution you suggest seems perfectly fine.

An other option may be to load your actions when loading and submit them to a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: I'm going to compare that date with current and if all is ok, I'm going to add some values to a variable and change this date in Database ChangeDate. Is it fine to do like that?

Comment: oh. and what number of records checking is critical in your opinion?